# Error: mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop

Tags: android, c++, qt, release, mingw32

I am trying to release really simple Qt app into .apk format using [Deploying an Application on Android tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html#androiddeployqt). In step one im getting make error "mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop.".

I have done:

Installed Qt (I did not know what is really needed so I ticked everything under Qt 5.11.0 and Tools), Android NDK r10e and Android SDK (again ticked full android-28 and Android 7.1). Set up paths in settings.

Written simple app (just combo box which writes selected index using qDebug()), I changed nothing in .pro file

Created empty directory D:\Android-Build where I want to release app so I changed Projects->Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.11.0 for Android armv7)->Build->Edit build configuration: Release->General->Build Directory to "D:\Android-Build" (Shadow Build is ticked)

Hit run qmake (by right click on project folder) and build

Opened cmd (basic windows one, not anything from Qt what pops up when I searched for "cmd") and navigated to my project folder D:\Users\User\Documents\QtProjects\Android\App01

Run "D:\Qt\5.11.0\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe --output D:\Android-Build --input D:\Android-Build\android-libApp01.so-deployment-settings.json" and it said: "Application binary is not in output directory: D:/Android-Build//libs/armeabi-v7a/libApp01.so. Please run 'mingw32-make install INSTALL_ROOT=D:/Android-Build/' first."

So I run "D:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make install INSTALL_ROOT=D:\Android-Build" and error "mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop." occured

Thanks for any ideas as I am completelly stuck here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it, I was runing make from mingw, not from android.

I should first navigate into `D:\Android-Build` directory and then run `C:\android-ndk-r10e\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe install INSTALL_ROOT=D:\Android-Build`